# VBS copy paste one cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, copy-paste

I have found vbscripts to copy ranges and between different worksheets, but who has a simple script for simply copying one cell to another in the same sheet?

I have tried this script, but without luck:

ws.Cell(2,35).Value = Cell(1,16)

Comment: Generally, you should first try yourself to copy one cell to another cell with automation and if something goes wrong, you should ask for help here with your specific and reproducible problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Cells` not `Cell` and you need to set the parent of both:

```
ws.Cells(2,35).Value =ws.Cells(1,16).value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Paste_Values_Examples()
    'Set a cell C1 value equal to another cell A1 value
    Range("C1").Value = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Copied from https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/